# Why program keeps printing trash values?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I wrote a function that takes a pointer to an index and checks if it's located within the limits of an array, the function prints the rest of the elements in that array if it's true, and if it's not, it prints "`Not in range`". The only parameters that this function gets are the array,the length of it and the pointer. The problem I have is that the loop that is responsible for iterating the array and printing the rest of the array also prints garbage values after the last element in the array.

Notes: you can't use any other local variables, only the parameters (array,length,pointer).  You also can't use `[]` operator, only pointer arithmetic.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void printAfterX(int* arr, int n, int* x);

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 4, 8, 6, 2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 5 };
    printAfterX(arr, 11, arr+6);
    return 0;
}

void printAfterX(int* arr, int n, int* x)
{
    if (x >= arr && x <= (arr + n)) //this checks if x is in the limits
    {
        x++;
        for (*arr = 0; *arr <= n; *arr++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *(arr + *x));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Not in range ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a de bugger and see what value you are passing for `x`.

Comment: 1) `(arr + n)` is past the array, not in it.  2) `*arr` gives a value stored in the array (if `arr` is valid), so it makes no sense to check it against the length... actually that whole `for` loop needs to be rethought.

Comment: `*arr <= n` checks whether the value `arr` points to is less than or equal to the number of elements. `*arr++` points `arr` to the next element, then dereferences for no reason.  `*(arr + *x)` gets the value in the array that `x` points to, then adds that to `arr` to get a pointer to that many elements past the element `arr` points at, then dereferences to get the value stored there (which is almost certainly the wrong thing to do).

Comment: When doing range checks like this, I find it massively helpful to keep all the comparisons in the same direction.  So I would write as `if (arr <= x && x < (arr+n))`.  This is not the source of your problem, so only a comment. (I have also corrected the `<=` vs `<` error, but that is a separate issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `x < (arr + n)`, not `x <= (arr + n)`. Note that there are a lot of other unchecked conditions in your code. For example, you never check whether or not the element in the array is less than `n` or not.

If you're not sure whether to use `<` or `<=`, you can always do a simple test case in your head: Asssume that your array has two elements, then `arr + 0` is valid, `arr + 1` is valid, `arr + 2` is not. So your `n` has to be less than 2.

Answer (score 1):

In your for-loop you will always print `n` numbers, starting from `x`. Also you set the first element of your array to zero and use it as iterator in `for (*arr = 0; *arr <= n; *arr++)`. As a result you will print numbers that are outside of the range of your array. I would recommend to use another approach on the for-loop like this:

```
    for ( ; x != arr+n; x++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *x);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you describe as the specification I think there are two problems with this bit of code:

```
for (*arr = 0; *arr <= n; *arr++)
{
    printf("%d ", *(arr + *x));
}
```

Firstly, that loop is all wrong. You're comparing the current element that `arr` is pointing at and seeing if it's less than the length of the array. What you should be doing is using `n` to limit the number of times you go around the loop. You're also making the first element of the array be 0.

Secondly, you're printing random values which could possibly be outside of the array because unless `*x` is 0, you're not printing some arbitrary value, possibly beyond the end of `arr`.

Thirdly, your specification says that you want to print everything after the element pointed to by `x` and you're sort of trying to print everything.

Fixing all three problems you'd end up with code that looks like.

```
for (x++; x<arr+n; x++)
{
  printf("%d ", *arr);
}
```

and as mentioned elsewhere this `if (x >= arr && x <= (arr + n))` should be `if (x >= arr && x < (arr + n))` as otherwise you'll be OK if `x` is one element beyond the length of `arr`

Comment: This prints all elements *except* `x`, the spec asks to print all elements *after* `x`. Depending if that is meant to include `x` or not, one either needs `for (;x != arr+n;x++)` or `for (;++x != arr+n;)`

Comment: Doh! you're right - the original code is very misleading in what it's trying to do.